# Cannot type in Espruino IDE native with ESP32

Tags: ide, connection, port, esp32, espruino

I am trying to make a Javascript program on my ESP32 board. I have installed the Espruino IDE native edition for my computer (That's the only way I could get the IDE to connect to one of my ports). I'm able to connect to the port, but I cannot type in the application's terminal. I don't know if this will help but everytime I connect, the terminal says "`Unable to retrieve board information. Connection Error?`." I'm using the ESP32-DOWD-V3 chip. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It helped me with the firmware to change `--baud 921600 \` to `--baud 115200 \`.

```
esptool.py \
    --chip esp32 \
    --port  "/dev/tty.usbserial-13120" \
    --baud 115200 \
    write_flash \
    -z \
    --flash_mode "dio" \
    --flash_freq "40m" \
    0x1000 bootloader.bin \
    0x10000 espruino_esp32.bin \
    0x8000 partitions_espruino.bin
```